# Laravel Telescope is not adding telescope.php in config folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have tried to install telescope according to Jeffrey's video.

I am using the latest version of laravel. I have installed according to the laravel documentation for installing as dev.

But, don't get the file `config/telescope.php` and `app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProviders.php` in config folder.

Need to mention:
--I have used `use Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider` namespace in `AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: Did you publish the vendor files?

Comment: have you published? `php artisan telescope:publish` ??

Comment: Also, the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/telescope) has steps to install Telescope

Comment: You need to set `TELESCOPE_ENABLED` to true in your env and run `php artisan telescope:publish` if still not working, you can try `php artisan vendor:publish` and if still not working try deleting `/cache/packages.php` and `/cache/services.php` and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @kerbholz, yes.. i have looked on the documentation and published telescope.

Comment: @Dilip Hirapara published and got the telescope.php file in config folder.  But, don't get the app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php yet.

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu, i have run **php artisan telescope:publish** and got the telescope.php. But, don't get the app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php yet.

Comment: Can you specify steps you followed in your question?

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu, i have followed the following step:

1. composer require laravel/telescope --dev
2. php artisan telescope:install
3. php artisan telescope:publish
4. removed App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class from config/app.php
5. added use Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider namespace in AppServiceProvider.php to make it runable


My Question is:
TelescopeServiceProvider.php has not been added to App\Providers folder.

Comment: @tanjiya Are you saying you have installed telescope with `dev` flag?

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu, yes

Comment: @tanjiya Can  you confirm this gist https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/889dd4d8a6d45ef01484c1971e1be5fe is what you have done so far? if yes, let me know your OS.

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu, That don't work for my existing project. But, works for newly installed laravel project. and, i am using windows10.

Comment: @tanjiya  compare both installation changes, you will get the problem.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, i have removed telescope using **composer remove laravel/telescope** and removed TelescopeServiceProvider manually from AppServiceProvider. And installed again, it works!

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @tanjiya glad, you solved your issue, but you did not learned, what was the mistake is a loss.

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu, the problem was ... i have not followed the descriptive way to install telescope properly. That was one of the reason. And, the other was to register the TelescopeServiceProvider in AppServiceProvider. That needed to remove manually.

Comment: @tanjiya good, that will help you avoid this in future.